# Check the keyboard with Qt 5

Tags: keyboard, qt5

I didn't find a way, with Qt 5, to check the state of the keyboard.

I would like for instance to check if a specific key (arrow key, or any other key) is down.

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box. While Qt processes mouse and keyboard events, it keeps track of the status of the mousebuttons and the keyboard modifiers, and returns them in `Q(Gui)Application::mouseButtons()` and `keyboardModifiers()`.

So, you could do the same by means of a global event filter: install an event filter on `QCoreApplication`, or override `QCoreApplication::notify`; and keep track of *all* the keys' statuses. I'm not sure how much this is useful, though; why are you not just handling keypresses in the currently focused widget chain?

(Note that the above applies only when the Qt application has focus; if you're talking about detecting the keyboard status even when you don't have focus, Qt doesn't help at all.)